# How to Fix Howbrew path issue permanently in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am using linuxbrew to install node. That works well, unless, for the fact that I can only use node after I do the following path export.

```
export PATH="/home/ericel/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"
```

If I close that terminal and open a new terminal, I will still have to do the same PATh export in order to get my node working.

Is there anyway to fix this permanently?
I do brew doctor, I get the following instructions:

```
ericel@ericel-X401A:~$ brew doctor
Please note that these warnings are just used to help the Homebrew maintainers
with debugging if you file an issue. If everything you use Homebrew for is
working fine: please don't worry and just ignore them. Thanks!

Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /home/ericel/.linuxbrew/bin
This means that system-provided programs will be used instead of those
provided by Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:
  xzmore
  unlzma
  lzcmp
  brew
  xzegrep
  lzgrep
  lzdiff
  lzless
  lzma
  pkg-config
  xzfgrep
  xzdiff
  xz
  lzfgrep
  lzcat
  lzegrep
  unxz
  xzgrep
  xzcat
  xzless
  lzmore
  lzmainfo
  xzcmp

Consider setting your PATH so that /home/ericel/.linuxbrew/bin
occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner:
  echo 'export PATH="/home/ericel/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Warning: Homebrew's bin was not found in your PATH.
Consider setting the PATH for example like so
  echo 'export PATH="/home/ericel/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile

Warning: You have a non-Homebrew 'pkg-config' in your PATH:
  /usr/bin/pkg-config

`./configure` may have problems finding brew-installed packages using
this other pkg-config.

Warning: Homebrew's share was not found in your XDG_DATA_DIRS but you have
this variable set to include other locations.
Some programs like `vapigen` may not work correctly.
Consider setting the XDG_DATA_DIRS for example like so
    echo 'export XDG_DATA_DIRS="/home/ericel/.linuxbrew/share:$XDG_DATA_DIRS"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

But even after doing that, node will work just for that one terminal. I am using ubuntu 16.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just had the same error. I think it was, because I installed linuxbrew at first from official page instructions and then i used apt-get.

So I removed the apt-get installation

```
sudo apt remove linuxbrew-wrapper
```

and then just added the path to

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

as written in official documentation

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.linuxbrew/bin:$PATH"' >>~/.bash_profile
```

then you need to open new terminal for it to take effect.