# rgdal installation difficulty on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: r, ubuntu

I searched for an answer helping my situation to avoid duplicate, but to no avail.

I want to install 'rgdal' package to R on ubuntu 16.04 LTS. If I code in R-studio as follows

```
install.packages("rgdal", type = "source")
```

it gives the following error;

```
Installing package into ‘/home/kocesat/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
package ‘rgdal’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3)
```

Then I try to install libgdal1-dev , libproj-dev  as the following

```
$ sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev libproj-dev
```

It succesfully installed the dev files.Then I tried to install again "rgdal" in R-studio with the same command. It did not work again.

Then I  installed homebrew and try to get gdal with

```
~$ brew install gdal
```

it returned

```
Error: undefined method `rebuild' for    
#<BottleSpecification:0x000000015ddc60>
Please report this bug:
https://github.com/Linuxbrew/linuxbrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew  
/Troubleshooting.md#troubleshooting
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula  
/jpeg.rb:9:in `block in <class:Jpeg>'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb:91:in  
`instance_eval'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/software_spec.rb:91:in `bottle'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:1729:in `bottle'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
/jpeg.rb:7:in `<class:Jpeg>'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Taps/homebrew/homebrew-core/Formula
/jpeg.rb:1:in `load_formula'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:21:in `module_eval'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:21:in 
`load_formula'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:34:in
`load_formula_from_path'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:83:in `load_file'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:74:in `klass'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:70:in `get_formula'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formulary.rb:207:in `factory'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/dependency.rb:32:in `to_formula'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/dependency.rb:93:in `block in   
expand'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/dependencies.rb:9:in `each'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/dependencies.rb:9:in `each'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/dependency.rb:80:in `expand'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:1223:in 
`recursive_dependencies'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/requirement.rb:196:in `expand'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formula.rb:1229:in `recursive_requirements'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:313:in `expand_requirements'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:263:in `compute_dependencies'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:130:in `verify_deps_exist'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/formula_installer.rb:123:in `prelude'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:231:in `install_formula'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:93:in `block in install'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:93:in `each'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/Homebrew/cmd/install.rb:93:in `install'
/home/kocesat/.linuxbrew/Library/brew.rb:84:in `<main>'
```

Now, what I should I do? Any input will be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Fix Howbrew path issue permanently in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317870/how-to-fix-howbrew-path-issue-permanently-in-ubuntu)

Comment: Maybe you could try using `apt` instead of linuxbrew http://www.sarasafavi.com/installing-gdalogr-on-ubuntu.html 
 Also, your R is kinda old. You may want to consider update it as the latest CRAN version depends on `R > 3.3.0`. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgdal/index.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is what I use to install on Ubuntu 16.04 with the latest R-cran PPA repositories:

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/' 
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E084DAB9
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libgdal1-dev libproj-dev libgeos-dev
sudo apt-get install r-base-core
```

You can use another CRAN mirror depending on your location:
https://cran.r-project.org/mirrors.html

Then, `install.packages("rgdal")` should work.

If you want the latest spatial libraries on Ubuntu LTS versions, you can also use `ubuntugis` PPA: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntugis/ppa/ubuntu xenial main' 
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 314DF160
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: For Ubuntu 18.04, I wrote a blog post https://rtask.thinkr.fr/blog/installation-of-r-3-5-on-ubuntu-18-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/

Comment: libgdal1-dev? do you mean libgdal-dev

Comment: some of these libraries are out of data, e.g. using Linux Mint 20, this one fails  libgdal1-dev. 
I used this solution: https://gist.github.com/dncgst/111b74066eaea87c92cdc5211949cd1e

Comment: For Ubuntu 20.04, I wrote a new blog post: https://rtask.thinkr.fr/installation-of-r-4-0-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-and-tips-for-spatial-packages/

Answer (score 1):

If you're here because your travis integration fails, see [#5852](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/5852)

```
language: r
sudo: false
cache: packages
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
      - libgdal-dev
      - libproj-dev
```