# How install R package "udunits2" in Ubuntu

Tags: r, ubuntu, package

I'm trying to install the R package `udunits2` on Ubuntu :

```
sudo su - -c "R -e \"install.packages('udunits2', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\""
```

But I'm getting error :

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28) -- "Short Summer"
Copyright (C) 2017 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> install.packages('udunits2', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/udunits2_0.13.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 67182 bytes (65 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 65 KB

* installing *source* package ‘udunits2’ ...
** package ‘udunits2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for XML_ParserCreate in -lexpat... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking udunits2.h usability... yes
checking udunits2.h presence... yes
checking for udunits2.h... yes
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/share/R/include -DNDEBUG      -fpic  -g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g  -c udunits2_R.c -o udunits2_R.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o udunits2.so udunits2_R.o -ludunits2 -lexpat -lexpat -ludunits2 -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/udunits2/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘udunits2’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
 unable to load shared object '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/udunits2/libs/udunits2.so':
  libudunits2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/udunits2’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/Rtmp0X1Xn4/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("udunits2", repos = "http://cran.rstudio.com/") :
  installation of package ‘udunits2’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any idea how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Seems like you are missing the package `libudunits2`, which is required to install the R package `udunits2`. Try installing that first with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks ! would be great if you could help me to upgrade GDAL on Ubuntu, currently it is 1.11.3 and for sf package it should be bigger than 2. I have read [https://launchpad.net/~ubuntugis/+archive/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable] but when I try : `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable` it returns error : `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~ubuntugis/ubuntu/ubuntugis-unstable'.
ERROR: '~ubuntugis' user or team does not exist.
` do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Hi Ali, I am afraid I am not an Ubuntu expert myself either, I just know enough to get by.  Does this help: <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382368/rgdal-installation-difficulty-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts>? Otherwise you might consider asking that as a separate question on SO.

Comment: Thak you very much

Comment: Works fine in Mint 18.8 Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you know how I would do this without sudo permission? I am on a server - thanks!