# udunits2 R install: udunits2.h not found

Tags: r

I'm trying to install udunits2 in R in order to satisfy the dependency for the `ggforce` package. However, the installer keeps failing on the check for udunits2. I have tried the instructions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059517/how-install-r-package-udunits2-in-ubuntu/47059608#47059608) (udunits 2 devel is installed as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aH6O5.png).) 
and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42580809/9303877) thread, which produces the [same result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aogMN.png) as trying to `install.packages('udunits2')`.

I was able to get it working on my Mint machine by just installing udunits2-dev, however I'm quite new to Fedora, and am not sure what is causing this.

System info:

Fedora 28, R-3.4.4

**EDIT**

Error output when trying to install using `install.packages("udunits2", configure.args = "--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/bin/udunits2")`:

```
* installing *source* package ‘udunits2’ ...
** package ‘udunits2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -m64
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -m64 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -m64 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for XML_ParserCreate in -lexpat... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -m64 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking udunits2.h usability... no
checking udunits2.h presence... no
checking for udunits2.h... no
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... yes
-----Error: udunits2.h not found-----
     If the udunits2 library is installed in a non-standard location,
     use --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib' for example,
     or --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
     replacing paths with appropriate values for your installation.
     You can alternatively use the UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIB
     environment variables.
     If udunits2 is not installed, please install it.
     It is required for this package.
```

Comment: Please add the command outputs into your question (with appropriate formatting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Fedora the header file is installed in `/usr/include/udunits2`, c.f. this [Github issue](https://github.com/pacificclimate/Rudunits2/issues/14). Solution provided there:

```
sudo yum install udunits2-devel
```

Followed by:

```
install.packages("udunits2",configure.args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2/')
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: @wolff You are welcome. Please also follow my above request and include the error message as text in your question. This makes the question easier to find and therefore more useful to others facing a similar issue.

Comment: Done. Sorry about that, will keep in mind next time.

Comment: You may need to run `sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel` prior to installing `udunits2-devel`

Answer (score 4):

Get the source code for udunits2 from the website: ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/udunits

Download, compile, and install udunits2:

```
# Download the library
wget ftp://ftp.unidata.ucar.edu/pub/udunits/udunits-2.2.26.tar.gz

# Decompress the archive
tar xf udunits-2.2.26.tar.gz

# Navigate to the archive
cd ./udunits-2.2.26

# Configure the build for your system
./configure prefix=$HOME/.local

# Use 4 jobs to build quickly
make -j 4

# Install to our prefix
make install
```

Start a new R session and install the `udunits2` R package:

(Make sure to change `$HOME` to your actual home path)

```
install.packages(
  "udunits2",
   configure.args = '--with-udunits2-include=$HOME/.local/include/'
)
```

Tested on this system:

```
R version 3.4.0 (2017-04-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.5 (Santiago)
```

Answer (score 1):

As a supercomputer server user without permission of *sudo yum*, I found installing udunits2-devel quite diffcult. Alternatively, i found spack https://spack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html
quite useful for installing udunits2&units R packages:

```
spack install r-udunits2
spack install r-units
```

Spack will automatically install dependent packages, and i don't have to install udunits2-devel by myself. 
Since i installed units R package for ggforce R package, and ggforce can't be installed by spack, i need to load units before entering R and then install ggforce:

```
$source <(spack module tcl loads r-units)
$source <(spack module tcl loads r-udunits2)
$R
>install.packages("ggforce")
```

and everything worked well.