# Can't install gganimate dependencies

Tags: r, package, gganimate

I'm trying to install gganimate on R 3.4.4. If I try `devtools::install_github('thomasp85/gganimate')`, I get:

`ERROR: dependencies ‘transformr’, ‘sf’, ‘gifski’ are not available for package ‘gganimate’`

Attempting to install each of them leads to a chain of failed dependency installations. `sf` tells me `ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘units’`. `Units` tells me `If udunits2 is not installed, please install it.` `udunits2` tells me `ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘udunits2’.

And so on. If I try to install the other packages, I get similar issues and I have not encountered this before while installing an R package.

Is there something more general that I'm missing?

EDIT: The entire udunits2 installation reads as follows:

```
Installing package into ‘/home/arvcondor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/udunits2_0.13.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 67182 bytes (65 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 65 KB

* installing *source* package ‘udunits2’ ...
** package ‘udunits2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for XML_ParserCreate in -lexpat... no
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking udunits2.h usability... no
checking udunits2.h presence... no
checking for udunits2.h... no
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... no
-----Error: libudunits2.a not found-----
     If the udunits2 library is installed in a non-standard location,
     use --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib' for example,
     or --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
     replacing paths with appropriate values for your installation.
     You can alternatively use the UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIB
     environment variables.
     If udunits2 is not installed, please install it.
     It is required for this package.
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘udunits2’
* removing ‘/home/arvcondor/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/udunits2’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘udunits2’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpzhtzSg/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Please provide the entire stack for relevant errors. `udunits2` error has to have more which should be more informative.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thought it might be able to be answered without it so I didn't want to clog up the question with unneeded code, but here you go, thanks a bunch

Comment: You need to install `udunits2` for your linux first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47059517/how-install-r-package-udunits2-in-ubuntu

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50362201/udunits2-r-install-udunits2-h-not-found

Comment: Got it, didn't realize it all hinged on the udunits2 package. I have everything installed now, thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install udunits2 package for R3.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42287164/install-udunits2-package-for-r3-3)