# "caught segfault" when installing rgdal for tmap R package

Tags: r, ubuntu, rgdal, tmap, proj

My goal is to install `tmap` R package from CRAN. I have followed through this installation procedure prior to installing the `tmap` package:

https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/blob/master/ubuntu_17_installation.sh

After `install.packages("tmap")` I receive an error message that identifies the problem to be with the `rgdal` package.

Calling `install.packages("rgdal")`, I received the following:

**Beginning of Traceback error message:**

```
installing to /home/larnsce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgdal/libs
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded

 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x1e, cause 'memory not mapped'
```

**End of Traceback error message:**

```
22: tools:::.test_load_package("rgdal", "/home/larnsce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4")
An irrecoverable exception occurred. R is aborting now ...
Segmentation fault
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/home/larnsce/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.4/rgdal’
```

**My `sessionInfo()`:**

```
R version 3.4.2 (2017-09-28)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 17.04

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /usr/lib/libblas/libblas.so.3.7.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3.7.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=de_CH.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=de_CH.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=de_CH.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_CH.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] bindrcpp_0.2       ggalt_0.4.0        mapdata_2.2-6      maps_3.2.0         sp_1.2-5           ggmap_2.6.1        dplyr_0.7.4       
 [8] purrr_0.2.3        readr_1.1.1        tidyr_0.7.1        tibble_1.3.4       ggplot2_2.2.1.9000 tidyverse_1.1.1   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] reshape2_1.4.2     haven_1.1.0        lattice_0.20-35    colorspace_1.3-2   yaml_2.1.14        rlang_0.1.2        foreign_0.8-69    
 [8] glue_1.1.1         RColorBrewer_1.1-2 modelr_0.1.1       readxl_1.0.0       jpeg_0.1-8         bindr_0.1          plyr_1.8.4        
[15] stringr_1.2.0      munsell_0.4.3      gtable_0.2.0       cellranger_1.1.0   rvest_0.3.2        RgoogleMaps_1.4.1  mapproj_1.2-5     
[22] psych_1.7.5        labeling_0.3       knitr_1.17         forcats_0.2.0      extrafont_0.17     parallel_3.4.2     Rttf2pt1_1.3.4    
[29] broom_0.4.2        proto_1.0.0        Rcpp_0.12.13       KernSmooth_2.23-15 geosphere_1.5-5    scales_0.5.0.9000  jsonlite_1.5      
[36] proj4_1.0-8        mnormt_1.5-5       digest_0.6.12      rjson_0.2.15       hms_0.3            png_0.1-7          stringi_1.1.5     
[43] ash_1.0-15         grid_3.4.2         tools_3.4.2        magrittr_1.5       lazyeval_0.2.0     extrafontdb_1.0    pkgconfig_2.0.1   
[50] MASS_7.3-47        xml2_1.1.1         lubridate_1.6.0    assertthat_0.2.0   httr_1.2.1         R6_2.2.2           nlme_3.1-131      
[57] compiler_3.4.2
```

**Installing `rgdal` from source gives the following different segfault message:**

```
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x7fe075206833, cause 'invalid permissions'
```

**This might be relevant:**

```
./configure: line 2112: 21315 Aborted                 ./proj_conf_test2
checking PROJ.4: epsg found and readable... yes
./configure: line 2187: 21324 Aborted                 ./proj_conf_test3
checking PROJ.4: conus found and readable... yes
```

**Other related questions I have explored**

[trouble in installing rgdal on ubuntu 16.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47141398/trouble-in-installing-rgdal-on-ubuntu-16-04)

[rgdal installation difficulty on ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44382368/rgdal-installation-difficulty-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

**This is also posted as an issue on GitHub**

https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/issues/150